# Изменение типа данных переменной

Tags: c

Добрый день, как сделать, чтобы компилятор удалил и забыл переменную, чтобы её снова можно было инициализировать?
Нужно сделать так, чтобы переменная не меняла своего имени, но меняли свой тип данных.

```
 include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {

     float a = 10.10;
     float temp = a;
     free(a); // просто segmentation fault
     int a = (int)temp;
     printf("%d\n", a); // Должно быть 10
}
```

Comment: Никак. Переменная, созданная в стеке, существует до тех пор, пока программа выполняется в области видимости этой переменной (внутри фигурных скобок).

Comment: Есть мнение, что когда возникает такая потребность - нужно пересматривать или алгоритм, или всю архитектуру, или вообще свои жизненные принципы :) Даже если речь об указателях, для которых и  `void *` может прокатить.

Comment: @PinkTux Делать было нечего, хотелось прикрутить "динамическую типизацию" к си)))

Comment: А она там нужна? Юзаю С года с 1994 вроде, ни разу такой потребности не возникало.

Comment: @PinkTux Абсолютно согласен, практического смысла в этом нет, но было интересно узнать, возможно ли это реализовать.

Comment: @Teofelts  Зачем вам это надо? Лучше опишите задачу, где возникло такое предположение. Возможно, задача решается  по-другому.

Comment: Чтобы это узнать достаточно открыть любую книжку уровня "C для самых маленьких". Даже статья на вики начинается со слов *"C (рус. Си) — компилируемый статически типизированный язык программирования..."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Удобнее всего воспользоваться указателем типа void*.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
   void *a = NULL;

   a = (void*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   (*(int*)a) = 10;
   printf("%d\n", (*(int*)a));

   a = (void*)realloc(a, sizeof(float));
   (*(float*)a) = 0.1;
   printf("%f\n", (*(float*)a));

   a = (void*)realloc(a, sizeof(char));
   (*(char*)a) = 'A';
   printf("%c\n", (*(char*)a));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Для решения данной задачи можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что в языке *C* каждый блок (часть кода, находящаяся в фигурных скобках) образует собственную область видимости:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float temp;
    {
        float a = 10.1;
        temp = a;
    }
    int a = (int)temp;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, хитрый способ!

Comment: @Majestio Согласно стандарту языка C, допускается отсутствие инструкции `return` в функции `main`. В этом случае компилятор сам неявно добавит `return 0`.

Comment: Хм ...) Можно ссылочку на это?

Comment: @Majestio Можно. Правда, на английском. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138649/why-is-return-0-optional

Comment: Оно самое! Спасибо. Хотя, я не рад - чем меньше "умолчаний", тем проще. Иначе скоро будет востребована специальность IT-юрист :)).